# Putnam Competition Exercise (Calculus)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

Studying calculus I found the following exercise:

$f(x)$ is defined for $a<x<b$. Suppose that $f$ can be twice differentiable and show that for $a<x<b:$

$\displaystyle \frac{\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}-\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}}{x-b}=\frac{1}{2}f''(\beta)$

for some $a<\beta<b$.

I defined $\displaystyle g(x)=\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$ and used the fact that $f$ is twice differentiable to conclude that $g$ is differentiable and that for any $a<c<b$ there is a $d$ such that $\displaystyle g'(d)=\frac{g(c)-g(b)}{c-b}=\frac{\frac{f(c)-f(a)}{c-a}-\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}}{c-b}$.

Now, I would like to ask if what I have thought is correct and if that is the case, how could I show that $g'(d)=\frac{1}{2}f''(\beta)$ for some $a<\beta<b$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you defined has a removable singularity at $a$. With that removed, the function  is continuous on $[a,b]$, and is differentiable on $(a,b)$. Thus by the mean value theorem $\frac{f(x) - f(b)}{x-b}$ is equal to the derivative of $g$ at some intermediate point. Now 
$$g'(y) = \frac{ f(b)-f(y) }{(b-y)^2}-\frac{f'(y)}{b-y}$$
But also $f(b) = f(y) + f'(y)(b-y) + \frac 12 f''(\beta)(b-y)^2$. Plugging this into the equation gives the result.